# Can't display mongodb collection to view Laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I'm using MongoDb and Laravel for a demo.
I'm trying to get the collection from MongoDb and display it to view in Laravel. 
Here is my model:

```
class Account extends Eloquent
{

    public function getAllAccount() {
        $account = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('Account')->get();

        return $account;
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{

    public function index() {
        $acc = new Account();

        $data = $acc -> getAllAccount();

        return view('account', $data);
    }
}
```

And then, I display it to view:

```
@if(isset($data))
                @foreach($data as $dataValue)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $dataValue->_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dataValue->avail_balance }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dataValue->last_activity_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dataValue->open_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dataValue->pending_balance }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dataValue->cust_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dataValue->open_branch_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dataValue->open_emp_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dataValue->product_id }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                @endif
```

I set Controller in web.php:

```
Route::get('/account', 'AccountController@index');
```

But when I run this, it return nothing, just a blank page.
How I can fix that?
Thank you very much!

UPDATE:
I use dd($data) in my controller and here is all my collection:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to send the data back in a format the page can take.

In the `index()` method, change:

```
return view('account', $data);
```

to

```
return view('account', compact ('data');
```

To be pretty, you can use ->with() as well, but I like compact since you can move a lot of variables easily.

Comment: I got "Trying to get property '_id' of non-object" error

Comment: That's a different problem.  But, looks like id is an object, so need to flatten that out - rather than a single variable to get from the `$dataValue` object.   IE in your dump, _id is showing not a value, but another object.

Comment: it's type Object Id in mongo. I just a newbie so anyway to fix this?

Comment: I think first test to see if the above fixes your original problem.  Remove everything but the flat variable in your view to test, just leave `<td>{{ $dataValue->avail_balance }}</td>`.  If that works, you know you've got the view problem worked out per your question above.  Once that's working, figure out what the object that holds your '_id' is and it's relation, and then chain it to open it.  Something like `$dataValue->someObjectName->_id`.  That's really a different question - but this may help to bug hunt.  This might be a re-architecture on your model to help get the info you want.

Comment: Hmm but it's still not work. I continue get error: "Trying to get property 'avail_balance' of non-object". So complicated!

Comment: Ahh - I see - the object coming in is not a collection of objects, its a collection of arrays, thus the message trying to get a property from a non-object.  It's trying to get the properties from an array.  You need to get that array to a level you can foreach through - right now the `$dataValue` is an *array* of mixed items.   You can solve this by figuring out the structure of the array and compensating in the loop.  But that will take a little work.  At least you've got the view issue fixed - that's good.  Try echoing the `$dataValue` variable in array notation for the avail_balance field.